# What is the correct syntax for accessing translations in app blocks / theme app extensions in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-api

This link here mentions how to access translations for your app blocks but the example doesn't seem to work and seems to be for regular sections instead of app blocks:

https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema#locales

My locales section looks like the following:

```
    "locales": {
        "en": {
            "title": "Slideshow"
        },
        "fr": {
            "title": "Diaporama"
        }
    }
```

I've tried a bunch of different permutations using the name of my section and the name of the file but nothing works.  According to the documentation the below should work:

```
sections.[section-name].[translation-description]
```

I've also tried the two below which both don't work:

```
blocks.[section-name].[translation-description]
block.[section-name].[translation-description]
```

Something tells me I'm doing something wrong or Shopify's documentation is lacking.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can check Shopify's example theme extension app https://github.com/Shopify/product-reviews-sample-app/tree/main/theme-app-extension/locales

basically, you need this format

> { "blocks": {     "average-rating": {         "name": "Average Review Score",
> "settings": {           "stars_fill_color": {
> "label": "Stars color"          }
> }    } }}

for accesing a label you should do "t:blocks.average-rating.settings.stars_fill_color.label"